# Segmentation fault only when executing program via a makefile

Tags: c, memory, makefile

First an abstraction of my program:

```
int main ()
{
    My_Struct1 ms1; // sizeof (My_Struct1) is 88712 B  -- L1
    My_Struct2 ms2; // sizeof (My_Struct2) is 13208 B  -- L2

    // 1. Invoke parser to fill in the two struct instances.  -- L3

    printf ("%ul, %ul\n", &ms1, &ms2) // -- **L3b** doesn't produce seg. fault.

    my_fun (&ms1, &ms2); //  -- L4, does produce seg. fault.

    return 0;
}
```

**If** I run my program using **makefile**, then a segmentation fault occurs at **L4** (always).

**If** I execute my program **directly from shell** (./executable), then the segmentation does occur **sometimes but not always**.

The error is: **Segmentation fault: Cannot access memory at address** at L4 for &ms1 and &ms2 both. The type and location of the error is what was pointed out by **gdb**.

My **guess** is that the error is because of the **size of the structures**. 
Please explain in detail what is going.

The error behivour is same even after reducing the size of My_Struct1 to 8112 B and My_Struct2 to 1208 B.

I am working on:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Intel® Core™ i5-4200M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4
- 3.8 GiB memory
- gcc - 4.8.4

Comment: "even after reducing the size of My_Struct1 to 8112 B". Do you mean "KB"? 8112KB is about 8MB, which is a common value for the stack size limit in Linux. So unless you have increased the stack size limit, that will likely overflow the stack.

Comment: Your guess is a reasonable one, but without seeing the definition of `My_Struct1`, `My_Struct2`, and `my_fun` (in particular, what locals it declares; if it's a stack size issue, those may play a role), we couldn't say for sure.

Comment: Hold on while I get my crystal ball

Comment: It is 8112 B only, not KB as it is the value returned by the `sizeof ()` .
`My_Struct1` is a struct containing an array (of #defined size) of basic blocks and `My_Struct2` is a Symbol Table.
They are probably too big to post in a question, I will if you still suggest.
But **the major point** is that the statement _L3b_ (newly added) **doesn't produce a segmentation fault** but statement _L4_ does; as pointed out by **gdb**.

Comment: You should probably create a minimal, complete, verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can't see the definition of your structs or what `my_fun` is. A minor point is that you should not pass pointers to `printf` if the formatting is `%ul` (`printf` will expect `unsigned long`s and nothing else). For printing pointers you should use `%p` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, compile with all warnings & debug info. Probably with `CFLAGS= -g -Wall -Wextra` in your `Makefile`. Perhaps you might *sometimes* add some [sanitize instrumentation options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) such as `-fsanitize=address` or `-fsanitize=undefined` (then it could be worthwhile to upgrade your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler to [GCC 5](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) in march 2016).You might also want `-Wstack-usage=1000` [warning](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) & `-fstack-usage` [developer option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html).

Be very [afraid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Then, enable [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) dumps. Probably some `ulimit -c 100000` (or whatever number is realistic) in your `~/.bashrc` then start a *new* terminal; check with `cat /proc/self/limits` (a Linux specific command, related to [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) that the limits are well set. See [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html).

Run your faulty test, e.g. with `make test`. You'll get a `core` dump. Check with `ls -l core` and `file core`.

At last, do a post mortem debugging session. If your binary is `someprog`, run `gdb someprog core`.  Probably the first `gdb` command you'll type would be `bt`

Indeed, you are probably wrong in declaring quite large `struct` as local variables in `main`. The rule of thumb is to **restrict your call frame to a few kilobytes** at most (hence, never have a local variable of more than a kilobyte in the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)). So I would recommend putting your large `struct` in the heap (so use `malloc` and `free` appropriately, read about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)). But a typical call stack on Linux can grow to several megabytes.

Also, run your program with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

BTW, the correct format for `(void*)` pointers in `%p` so your added `printf` should be

```
printf("ms1@%p, ms2@%p\n", (void*)&ms1, (void*)&ms2);
```